# Where are the non-helpful people?

Tags: discussion, users, policy

In every other web forum I have ever asked a question on, with every question I will enevitably get at least one truly unhelpful reply, telling me my whole approach is wrong, asking me why I am using my language, platform, operating system, etc. instead of their favorite, telling me I should go back to progammer's school, etc. Mind you it's not just me, everybody gets them. Anyway, I don't see those here. What happens to them and their authors? Does your cousin Guido pay them a visit :)

Comment: Your approach is wrong - why are you using this language / platform / operating system instead of going back to programmer's school?

Comment: We're all right here on meta!

Comment: I did not ever expect to see this kind of question from this viewpoint. It is almost always the other way around.

Comment: I would consider this is a compliment to SO.

Comment: Did you ever consider that there might be some  truth in those answers?

Comment: This [is] meant as a compliment, I wasn't complaining that I didn't see them I was pleasantly amazed that I didn't see them.

Answer (score 14):

They're around. But you see them less, since the rest of us like to delete their answers: just about anyone can "flag" a comment or answer for removal, and down-voting also helps to discourage this sort of thing and can encourage users to delete their misguided responses.

That sort of behavior is *usually* inappropriate... If you do encounter it, flag and ignore.

Comment: I agree (and upvoted), although I also think the 'gentle' nature of the SO community can also be partly attributed to its 'young' age. I've seen the trolls arriving lately (rising along with SO popularity). I hope moderation keeps working as fine as it is now.

Comment: @ChristopheD: we'll have to see if it persists; I'm already impressed by how well it appears to be scaling though. IMHO, being able to close questions as duplicate or off-topic helps a great deal in reducing the sort of newbie noise that so often drives old-timers mad on forums.

Answer (score 10):

Unhelpful replies will be downvoted, generally. Few people seem to do this regularly, and if they *do* then the moderators may well get in touch - and the same will happen if answers are flagged as offensive or spam.

The moderation system on SO seems to work remarkably well, to be honest...

Comment: I would say - unbelievably well. Facing real spam once a few months only.

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of answers saying "your approach is wrong" but they are usually done in a reasonably helpful way, with an explanation why it is wrong and suggested alternatives.

Comment: This. In part because you're not going to get any votes unless you explain *why* they're doing it wrong *and* suggest a better way, now are you.

Comment: I generally don't find that SO users are *shy* about sharing their opinion of why your question is wrong. But, they do it in a reasonable way, and they back up their opinion with some kind of evidence. That's the right way!

Answer (score 4):

Next time you see one of those unhelpful people, thank them on behalf of all of us. Their counter-productive behavior is exactly what inspired Jeff and Joel to create Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank them with a download or a flag.

Comment: Emm... Wasn't it expertsexchange's bad business practices which inspired them to create SO.

Answer (score 2):

When you talk about "unhelpful people" are you talking about *truly* unhelpful people, or [people who only seem unhelpful because the real answer is the one you weren't looking for](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx)?

The former tend to get flagged, deleted, and/or down-voted to oblivion. The community tends to deal with these types fairly quickly.

The latter sometimes get down-voted to oblivion, sometimes they end up as high rep users.

Answer (score 2):

Legitimate cases of where the asker is taking the wrong approach are pointed out. [The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Oh, my, that's a very important link. It should be on the meme thread.

Answer (score 2):

They usually embed their unhelpful/snide comment in their correct answer

Answer (score 1):

My cat's breath smells like cat food.

Comment: That is one of my all-time favorite Ralph quotes!

Comment: @pkaeding: second only to, "It tastes like burning."

Comment: I choo choo choose you

Comment: I have no idea what just happened here.

Answer (score 0):

[They](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31915/where-are-the-non-helpful-people/31934#31934) all hang out on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).